# Redux-orm linking constraints on dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-orm

Trying to understand redux-orm . Have been reading up on 
and https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm and
http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/practical-redux-part-1-redux-orm-basics/

I have two classes Author and Book

[image: Author]

[image: Book]

Now when i dispatch an **CREATE_AUTHOR** action creating author details similarly i dispatch another action with type **CREATE_BOOK** adding Book details . 
Now how do i link the Author and its associated books ? or if i am creating a Book first how to i add its Author ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies [in the documentation itself here](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm#redux-integration). You need to create another action like `ADD_AUTHOR_TO_BOOK` that would do the linking for you